# is that correct to call an axios method inside created?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm  working on a small project using VueJS and I would like to know if my code is considered as a good practice :

```
created(){
    this.fetch()
}
methods: {
    fetch(){
       // axios request
    }
}
```

Comment: In larger applications, it would be better to extract this axios request outside of your component (into a store -Vuex- or a separate service) to centralize your data and allow for reusability. But as long as your code is easy to maintain, there is nothing wrong with doing it this way

Comment: A better practice is to call it on mount. create vs mounted can be chosen per need basis, and async requests don't benefit from being performed ASAP in created.

Comment: @EstusFlask tbh why is there no benefit calling a async method earlier on a `created` lifecycle instead of a `mounted` which is definitely a tiny bit slower?
If you just handle data and stick on the DOM reactivity it makes more sens calling your API inside created.

Comment: @Deniz It's semantically incorrect to put async side effects into `created` because they won't finish at the time when next hook (`mounted`) runs, while this is commonly expected and appears in similar newbie questions. I don't remember exactly if this causes problems with SSR as well but I believe it is. `created` runs a couple of ms earlier but putting anything that doesn't belong there there will postpone the first paint. This clearly translates to composition API, async components do `await` in `setup` for blocking requests, non-blocking async side effects go to `onMounted`.

Comment: @EstusFlask `mounted` and `created` run separate from each other, so far so good.
If we think about just simply call a fetch from a api, which in our context of a usually SPA is getting data only, like json. we can get rid of the situation that the dom is not fully rendered, which is happening after the `mount`.
It's like you have a racing car in a race which starts the engine first at that very moment the race starts instead of starting it before the start signal hits green. There are no side effects in a async created block afaik.

Comment: @Deniz *we can get rid of the situation that the dom is not fully rendered* - I'm not sure what scenario you describe. Calling `fetch` in `created` won't make data ready at the time when the component is rendered any way. The optimization you talk about is negligible and potentially harmful (see the remark on SSR). You can save a couple of ms on the average on preferring `created`, this cannot be compared to the time that a request takes, and this happens at the cost of initial render time if `fetch` is bulky enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a Vue method from the created life cycle hook. That's perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

Here there is few [examples](https://scotch.io/@bedakb/lets-build-type-ahead-component-with-vuejs-2-and-fetch-api) of the same thing that you are doing:

The link is from the VueJs [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html#Fetch-API) itself.

Yes, they are doing the same things.

Answer (score 0):

if you plan to add more stuff into your created block which could depending your fetched data then you should keep in mind you have to `await` your data

```js
async created(){
    await this.fetch()
    // other stuff here which needs the data above
}
methods: {
    fetch(){
       // axios request
    }
}
```

Comment: @AliceMunin that can't be. update your initial question please and add the code